# RoR, params not being passed to the controller for a :remote link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Ok ill be honest, i haven't spent much time looking for a solution yet seeing as how my son is keeping my attention running around. Either way I would like to ask a question for something that seems pretty simple but has stumped me thus far.

So to keep it simple lets say I have Users(w/model) and Home controllers, Home is the root route.

In the root directory I want to be able to see all posts made by the User using ajax to update a partial on the home page with the list of posts.

In the **users** controller I have a def called **userposts** with this in it

```
def userposts
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @userposts = @user.posts.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { @userposts}
  end    
end
```

And in my view I have

```
<p id="aboutuser">
  <% if @user.about? %>
    <%= "   " + @user.id.to_s %>
  <% else %>
    User has not yet filled this out.
  <% end %>
</p> 
<h3 id="authpostlink">
  <%= link_to "List of all posts", user_userposts_path(@user.id), :id => @user.id, :remote => true %>
</h3>
```

my errors are as follows

> Started GET "/users/2/userposts" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Jan 15 13:36:23
>   -0600 2012   Processing by UsersController#userposts as JS   Parameters: {"user_id"=>"2"}   User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".*
>   FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1 Completed 500 Internal
>   Server Error in 1ms
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass):
>
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:27:in`userposts'
>
> Rendered
>   /home/n0de/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb
>   (0.8ms) Rendered
>   /home/n0de/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb
>   (0.8ms) Rendered
>   /home/n0de/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (3.2ms)

I do realize i did not post the `_show.js.erb` file  that calls the action to update the div but according to the error messages it doesn't seem the process has gotten that far.

Comment: The problem seems to be in your routse.rb, can you post that?

Comment: Is `@user` null? Have you added a new RESTful action to the user resource? Also, I think you should just be passing in `@user` to `user_userposts_path` if you've added it as a method `:on => :member` as described in the [routing docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following:

```
# /app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

# /app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I would add a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) in your routes file:

```
#/config/routes.rb
resources :users do
  resources: posts
end
```

You get a bunch of great "_path" methods for free (run `$ rake routes` from your console to see them all), and it gives you access to URLs such as /users/123/posts. This request will go to the index method of your PostsController and will automatically include :user_id => 123 in the params hash. You can then do the following:

```
# In your view:
<%= link_to "List of all posts", user_posts_path(@user), :remote => true %>
<div id="posts"></div>

# /app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js # allows for AJAX requests

  def index
    if params[:user_id].present? # Do this if using the nested resource
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @posts = @user.posts.order('posts.created_at DESC')
    else # Otherwise, treat it like a normal request
      @posts = Post.all
    end
    respond_with @posts
  end
end
```

Because the your request is sent remotely, you need a corresponding "js" version of your index view (note the file name below and see [this Railscast for more explanation](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript)):

```
# /app/views/posts/index.js.erb
$('#posts').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@posts)) %>");
```

This will render out the posts into that `<div id="posts">` tag. (You'll probably need a "_post.html.erb" partial in /app/views/posts/" as well.)

However, having said all this, are you sure you need to do this via AJAX? You could simply preload all the posts in the UsersController#show method, initially hide the list using CSS, and then add a jQuery toggle() method on that link. Anyway, hope this makes sense and is helpful.

Comment: Thank you much, it was something i overlooked (I was tired and names the js file "_userposts.js.erb" instead of "userposts.js.erb", while i did end up using your method posted to get this working I also reverted back to my old code to see why it didnt work and with the file name change my old code was right on. But in any case, Thank you for the help.